# Compute integral: $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate the following definite integral
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{1+x^2}dx
$$

What I have done is

> I substitute $t=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}$,
> after simplify I got
> $$
> \int\dfrac{t^2}{t^4+1} dt
> $$

> But the integral of the above expression is bit more lengthy.

Comment: How did you simplify the integrand to $\displaystyle{\dfrac{t^2}{t^4+1}}$? It is incorrect, please include your work and check again.

Comment: You miss a factor $4$, which should be $\displaystyle\frac{4t^2}{t^4+1}$

Comment: @Dstarred No, $\frac{4t^2}{t^4+1}$ is correct.

Comment: Ya sorry 4 factor should be there @MathFail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$I=\int\frac{t^2}{1+t^4}dt$$

$$\begin{align}I&=\int\frac{1}{t^2+t^{-2}+2-2}dt=\int\frac{1}{(t+t^{-1})^2-2}dt\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\int\frac{1}{t+t^{-1}-\sqrt2}-\frac{1}{t+t^{-1}+\sqrt2}dt\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\int\frac{t}{t^2-\sqrt2~t+1}dt-\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\int\frac{t}{t^2+\sqrt2~t+1}dt\end{align}$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Even after this the process is a bit lengthy...I hope there is some trick to evaluate this Integral

Comment: @MathFail yes i can proceed from here using atan

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{t^2}{1+t^4} d t 
& =\int \frac{1}{t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}} d t \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)+\left(1-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)}{t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}} d t \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{d\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)}{\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)^2+2}+\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{d\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)}{\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)^2-2} \\
& =\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{t-\frac{1}{t}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2}} \ln \left|\frac{t+\frac{1}{t}-\sqrt{2}}{t+\frac{1}{t}+\sqrt{2}}\right|+C
\end{aligned}
$$